# Matching one or more keywords with Django's Postgres full-text searching

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

If I search on a website with multiple keywords (and no quotes) -- such as for *red car* -- my expectation is that items containing "red car" exactly should be first, followed by items containing both keywords (but non-sequentially), followed by items containing one of the keywords. *(I believe this is the default behavior in Lucene-like systems, but it's been a while since I've used them, so can't say for sure.)*

My hope was that the Postgres full-text searching would automatically do this, but my early tests show this is not the case:

```
## ASSUME: items in database: <blue car>, <green car>, <red truck>

keywords = "red car"
items = ForSaleItem.objects.filter(name__search=keywords)

## RESULT: items is empty/None, whereas it should have each of 
##         the items since one keyword matches.
```

The hack I'm seeing is to using Django's disjunction operator, but I'm hoping there is something less-hacky. I'm also pretty sure this hack wouldn't put exact matches at the top of the list. Here's the hack:

```
from django.db.models import Q
keyword_query = Q()
for keyword in keywords.split(' '):
    keyword_query.add(Q(name__search=keyword), Q.OR)
items = ForSaleItem.objects.filter(keyword_query)
```

Is there some settings/API that I'm missing (or something implementable on the postgres side) that gets the functionality I'm expecting?

Comment: Are you looking for multi key word search?    
`SearchQuery('red') & SearchQuery('car') # red AND car`  

`SearchQuery('red') | SearchQuery('car') # red OR car`

Comment: Thanks @Dharshan, you got me to re-read the docs and discover the combination of your suggestion of `SearchQuery('red') | SearchQuery('car')` with the `SearchRank()` class accomplishes what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Dharshan for pointing me in the right direction. As he or she noted, the disjunction of `SearchQuery` objects will allow matching of either keyword. Additionally, to have items that contain both keywords at the top of the list --
 as described in the [Django full text search docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchrank) -- the `SearchRank` class can be used as follows:

```
vector = SearchVector('name')
query = SearchQuery('red') | SearchQuery('car')
items = ForSaleItem.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = ForSaleItem.objects.filter(name__contains=keywords)
```

Comment: This does not work; it results in an error: "Unsupported lookup 'search' for CharField or join on the field not permitted."

Comment: Provide your models.

Comment: My model is simply `ForSaleItem` with one field, `name=CharField()`.  Note that `__search` in my context is not a field; it is the built-in keyword from [Django's Full Text Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#full-text-search) feature.  It looks like Dharshan's comment is more to what I was looking for, so I'll relay that in the comments above.